# Kamon is not reporting the data to prometheus

Tags: scala, playframework, prometheus, kamon

I have web service which is built using `scala-play(version 2.5.12)` framework. Trying to capture metrics using `kamon` and `prometheus`.

Below is the code snippet which i have done so far.

Dependencies:

```
"io.kamon" %% "kamon-play-2.5" % "1.1.0",
"io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % "1.1.0",
"org.aspectj" % "aspectjweaver" % "1.9.2",
"io.kamon" %% "kamon-prometheus" % "1.1.1"
```

conf/application.conf

```
kamon {
  metric {
    tick-interval = 1 second
  }

  metric {
    filters {
      trace.includes = [ "**" ]
      akka-dispatcher.includes = [ "**" ]
    }
  }

  modules {
    kamon-log-reporter.auto-start = no
  }
}
```

I have initialized the `kamon reporter` in one of my config file.

```
import kamon.Kamon
import kamon.prometheus.PrometheusReporter  

Kamon.addReporter( new PrometheusReporter() )
```

I am adding tracing in one of my controller

```
import kamon.play.action.OperationName

override def test(userName: Option[String]): Action[JsValue] = OperationName("test-access")  {
    Action.async(parse.json) {
      ......
    }
  }
```

I am building the jar and running in local with below command

```
/bin/example-app -J-javaagent:./lib/org.aspectj.aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar -Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default
```

Application is running and i can see in the logs that reporter has started. 
Below is the log

`2018-12-07 12:06:20,556 level=[INFO] logger=[kamon.prometheus.PrometheusReporter] thread=[kamon.prometheus.PrometheusReporter] rid=[] user=[] message=[Started the embedded HTTP server on http://0.0.0.0:9095]`

But I don't see anything in `http://localhost:9095/metrics`. It is empty.

There is no error and unable to debug this. Is there anything i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://kamon.io/documentation/1.x/reporters/prometheus/) says that the metrics are exposed at `http://localhost:9095/`. There is no `metrics` endpoint.

Comment: I have tried with this as well. It did not work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: if you specify target as 'localhost:9095', prometheus will query http://localhost:9095/metrics (Prometheus agent will respond on on any path like http://localhost:9095/hello or http://localhost:9095/anything-else ). So your statement is incorrect, prometheus has 'metrics' endpoint.